# How to map nodes in an array in Mule 3

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to get value from `offers.offer.productOffers.productOffer`.
Required `uri` and `id` from `offers.offer.productOffers.productOffer`.
I am using DataWeave 1.0.
Not able to return the required value using map. Returning a null value.

Sample payload

```
{
   "offers":{
      "uri":"https",
      "offer":[
         {
            "uri":"https",
            "id":454645464,
            "name":"Shipping -Test",
            "policyName":null,
            "type":"Shipping Order Value",
            "image":null,
            "trigger":"Always Triggered",
            "salesPitch":[
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null
            ],
            "customAttributes":{
               
            },
            "productOffers":{
               "uri":"https"
            },
            "categoryOffers":{
               
            },
            "offerBundleGroups":{
               
            }
         },
         {
            "uri":"https",
            "id":63501325815,
            "customAttributes":{
               
            },
            "productOffers":{
               "uri":"https",
               "productOffer":[
                  {
                     "uri":"https",
                     "id":9877897987
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to access those values directly because payload.offers.offer s an array, and productOffer is another array.

So `payload.offers.offer.productOffers.productOffer` will return an array of arrays:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "uri": "https",
      "id": 9877897987
    }
  ]
]
```

You could use the `flatten` operator to remove one level of nested arrays  `flatten(payload.offers.offer.productOffers.productOffer)`:

```json
[
  {
    "uri": "https",
    "id": 9877897987
  }
]
```

From that it depends on how you want to process the list of uri and id elements.

Comment: flatten(payload.offers.offer.productOffers.productOffer) worked